# Error in Eclipse for Mobile Developers(JUNO)

Tags: android, eclipse

when I run eclipse, showes this information:

[image]

what means this message? why should Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you should install the command line tools for git. Here are directions:
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git